how to update serial value in a playbook that depends on the number of hosts in a group
my playbook looks like
- hosts: web:back:front
  serial: "{{ groups[group_names[0]] | length }}"

when i execute, it doesn't seem to work as the error points out that group_names variable is undefined
How can i get the serial value to match the number of hosts in the current group ?

Please define "current group". Note that the serial expression in templated before tasks are actually executed so the variables specific to a given hosts (e.g. the groups the host is a member of as group_names) are not available.
